# adding ssl to webapi... also to client?

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to understand SSL fundamentals.  (using Microsoft Azure cloud services)
In Azure I have purchased a SSL certificate, and binded it to my custom domain.  Seems to be working fine.  My question is on implementation...

when making the webapi call from the client, some docs tell me just make the call like so...

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foobar.com/");
```

But I'm also seeing sometimes I have to add the certificate to the program that I make the call from.

```
//You must change the path to point to your .cer file location. 
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\mycert.cer");
// Handle any certificate errors on the certificate from the server.
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new CertPolicy();
// You must change the URL to point to your Web server.
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://YourServer/sample.asp");
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
Request.UserAgent = "Client Cert Sample";
Request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

My question is, when do I simply add the https to the httpclient, and when do I have to add the certificate to the actual client?

Comment: Adding the client certificate to the request is mandatory for https. (*you might have used a self-signed certificate, which is free*)

Comment: I'm using HttpClient on desktop client to make calls... your saying I HAVE to add the certificate to this httpclient httpresponsemessage?

Comment: No, the client certificate is for the request. The server certificate is automatically returned in the response. You are then free in the client to check or not the server certificate in your client.

Comment: I purchased a server certificate right from Azure, where do I get this client certificate?

Comment: Create a self signed certificate. For testing, It might be identical to server certificate.

Comment: sorry, still confused, what is the difference between the certificate I purchased right on Azure, and this self signed certificate?

Comment: The difference is that purchased certificates are issued by a known "certification authority".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, when do I simply add the https to the httpclient, and when do I have to add the certificate to the actual client?

This is a **client -> server** call over a secure channel (TLS). This is what everybody normally does and how your browser works when you open a HTTPS URL:

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foobar.com/");
```

This is a **client -> server** call over a secure channel (TLS) which is **also doing TLS Mutual Authentication** (also dubbed **Client Certificate Authentication**). The Client has to prove its identity to the server (by presenting a certificate, `X509Certificate Cert`), same goes for the server towards the client - hence the *mutual*:

```
//You must change the path to point to your .cer file location. 
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\mycert.cer");
// Handle any certificate errors on the certificate from the server.
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new CertPolicy();
// You must change the URL to point to your Web server.
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://YourServer");
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
Request.UserAgent = "Client Cert Sample";
Request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

You would use the first one to do **SECURE** calls and the 2nd one (mutual authentication) to do **SECURE AND AUTHENTICATED** calls (e.g. Your Web App calls a backend API that you own).

Actually it's more like **SECURE WITH VERIFIED IDENTITY** but we're opening a can of worms here so let's leave it at that.

Comment: so if I just want basic ssl, then I only need to change the .baseaddress and be done with it?